# Can my mother get a new US visa when she didn't use the previous one?

Tags: visas, usa

I need help.

My Mum is 77 years old. She got a 2-year US visa that she didn't use because my sister, who was supposed to take her to the US, was very busy. My sister is now ready to travel, but my mum's visa will expire in less than 3 weeks. Can my mum do drop box renewal? Will the visa be issued again?

Comment: If she's traveling within three weeks, she doesn't need a new visa.  It only needs to be valid on the day of arrival.

Answer (score 5):

**Can my mum do drop box renewal?**

No. Drop box renewals aka  Visa Interview Waiver Program have been suspended by Donald Trump through [Executive Order 13780](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/executive-order-protecting-nation-foreign-terrorist-entry-united-states-2/)

> **Suspension**
>
> Sec. 9. Visa Interview Security. (a) The Secretary of State shall immediately suspend the Visa Interview Waiver Program and ensure compliance with section 222 of the INA, 8 U.S.C. 1202, which requires that all individuals seeking a nonimmigrant visa undergo an in-person interview, subject to specific statutory exceptions.

**Will the visa be issued again?**

Nobody knows. She will find out at the interview.

Comment: It should be clarified here not using the visa doesn't incur any prejudice against issuing a new visa.